# How to get href and label of first file of sharepoint using c# and how to download fist file of sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, download, label, href

I'm new to c#.
Help me how to get SharePoint href and label values.
How to download the first file from SharePoint.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. It is unclear what you are asking and seems that you are asking several questions. I have flagged your question as too broad. please pick one question and elaborate clearly on it. please also provide a minimal reproducible example of the c# you have tried.

Comment: Shared the code .i want to download  sharepoint file but with this code  it's showing dowloded but not  downloded  in my localdisc .

Answer (score 0):

```
  String url="MYURL"
   string fileName = "MYFILENAME", myStringWebResource = null;
   WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
     myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;

  Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);

  myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);   

   Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);

     Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + path);
```